# Loading GAP packages in Sagemath Cloud

Tags: sage, gap-system

I'm trying to load some GAP packages in a Sagemath Cloud terminal session without sucesss.  For example, when I try to load the SCSCP package I get the following error:

```
sage: gap.load_package( "SCSCP" )
-----------------------------------------------------------------    

RuntimeError                    Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-37-249a04a6b510> in <module>()
 ----> 1 gap.load_package( "SCSCP" )

/usr/local/sage/sage-6.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/gap.pyc in load_package(self, pkg, verbose)
     506         if x == 'fail':
     507             raise RuntimeError("Error loading Gap package "+str(pkg)+". "+
 --> 508                                "You may want to install the     gap_packages SPKG.")
     509
     510     def eval(self, x, newlines=False, strip=True, split_lines=True, **kwds):

RuntimeError: Error loading Gap package SCSCP. You may want to install the gap_packages SPKG.
```

I thought it would be possible to at least load packages by starting a GAP session using `gap.console()` but this also fails.

```
sage: gap.console()
 ┌───────┐   GAP, Version 4.7.5 of 24-May-2014 (free software, GPL)
 │  GAP  │   http://www.gap-system.org
 └───────┘   Architecture: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-default64
 Libs used:  gmp, readline
 Loading the library and packages ...
 Components: trans 1.0, prim 2.1, small* 1.0, id* 1.0
 Packages:   Alnuth 3.0.0, AtlasRep 1.5.0, AutPGrp 1.6, CTblLib 1.2.2, FactInt 1.5.3, GAPDoc 1.5.1, LAGUNA 3.6.4, Polycyclic 2.11, TomLib 1.2.4
 Try '?help' for help. See also  '?copyright' and  '?authors'
gap> LoadPackage( "IO" );
fail
gap> LoadPackage( "SCSCP" );
fail
gap>
```

Comment: Can you make your own installation of GAP there and build all packages that you need?

Comment: Hi, it appears that before starting sage in the cloud terminal, there is an option to install additional GAP packages via `sage -i <package name>`.  This is described on [this page](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/interfaces.html).

To list these optional packages I did `sage -optional` which gives me a list of various packages to load with Sage, but the only GAP related one seems to be `gap_packages-4.6.4.p1`.  However, I don't have write access to the packages directory.  So maybe I have to use `sudo` using my cloud account password.

Comment: It does say that "Some non-GPL’d GAP packages may be installed by downloading them from the GAP web site [GAPkg], and unpacking them in $SAGE_ROOT/local/lib/gap-4.4.10/pkg. )".  I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: OK, let me know if you will have any luck. IMHO just installing GAP from scratch will be easier...

Comment: I was just thinking that it may be simpler to write a GAP script on my local system since it has SCSCP.  That might be the best solution.